# I want to send a message to a specific user after someone joined into a specific channel

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So, I want my Discord bot to send a message to a specific user whenever someone joins into a specific channel. But my code doesn't seem to work.
Does someone know how to fix it?

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
let newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel
let oldUserChannel = oldMember.voiceChannel

if(oldUserChannel === undefined && newUserChannel !== undefined) {
    if(voiceChannel.id === "530501827389685762"){

        client.users.get("188984116618854400").send("Ein neuer Spieler ist im Aufnahmebereich!")

    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}
```

})

Answer (score 1):

On line 6, you write:

```
if (voiceChannel.id ...
```

`voiceChannel` is not defined.
For future reference, include the error. Some style remarks:
1. the else and return statement are unnecessary if that's the end of your function
2. research truthy and falsy values in javascript, they can save you some time checking if channels are undefined.